# Node Defender Console doesn't show console.error() messages

Tags: javascript

https://node-defender.herokuapp.com/

Is there a way to get meaningful feedback? I'm getting an error that doesn't make sense and I want to check that the function I made is actually returning a mob object instead of "undefined", which it shouldn't be.

Console.error isn't showing up in the console on the right when I run my code. Is there another way to get meaningful feedback from my code so that I can debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier/quicker to do the console.log or console.error and look at the actual browser console instead of relying on the in-game console.

Comment: I realized that the console messages and the Message Window were independent of each other after you made this post. Still, it would be neater if these types of things, like Robot Fight Code and Node Defender had API calls for output.

Comment: You could always add it as a patch. Node defender is open source: https://github.com/zumba/node-defender/blob/master/public/js/lib/brain.js#L49. You'd just need to pass blabber into that and then you'd have access to the console API.